# String parametern in URL on server side gets wrong decoding

Tags: java, android, spring, resttemplate

When I am trying to send URL to server, it's look like: 
[http://192.168.0.80:8080/directory/getCertainServices/1/Кузовные](http://192.168.0.80:8080/directory/getCertainServices/1/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5) работы

But on the server side "Кузовные работы" parameter looks like:

```
ÐÑÐ·Ð¾Ð²Ð½ÑÐµ ÑÐ°Ð±Ð¾ÑÑ
```

I am using RestTemplate from spring framework to send data from client:

```
@Override
        protected Service[] doInBackground(Object... voids) {
            restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            return restTemplate.getForObject(customURL, Service[].class);
        }
```

Server side code:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/getCertainServices/{autoServiceId}/{serviceCategory}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Object> getService(@PathVariable("autoServiceId") Long autoServiceId, @PathVariable("serviceCategory") String serviceCategory){
        return dataBaseServiceService.findByAutoServiceAndCategory(autoServiceId, serviceCategory);
    }
```

Can anyone give an advice what's the problem here ?

**UPDATE QUESTION:**
Does this mean that I have to use only english words in URL path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat Wiki has a good page called "[Character Encoding Issues](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding)" that describes the problem pretty well.

The solution depends on the actual web server being used, but if it's Tomcat (default for Spring), the solution is on that wiki page:

> **How do I change how GET parameters are interpreted?**
>
> Tomcat will use ISO-8859-1 as the default character encoding of the entire URL, including the query string ("GET parameters") (though see Tomcat 8 notice below).
>
> There are two ways to specify how GET parameters are interpreted:
>
> - Set the `URIEncoding` attribute on the  element in server.xml to something specific (e.g. `URIEncoding="UTF-8"`).
> - Set the `useBodyEncodingForURI` attribute on the  element in server.xml to `true`. This will cause the Connector to use the request body's encoding for GET parameters.
>
> In Tomcat 8 starting with 8.0.0 (8.0.0-RC3, to be specific), the default value of `URIEncoding` attribute on the  element depends on "strict servlet compliance" setting. The default value (strict compliance is off) of `URIEncoding` is now `UTF-8`. If "strict servlet compliance" is enabled, the default value is `ISO-8859-1`.